# What is the correct way to create an IIF expression with DLookUp in Access?

Tags: nested, iif, dlookup

My name is Jaime and I'm been building a Access DB from scratch, looking and watching information in the internet, so I'm a totally rooky on this, looking for some help from this great community. I Hope someone can help me.

I have a form (tbl2_RFQ_Details1) where I have the Items to need to buy for build machinery. Every record has one or more quotes regarding the Item needed (see pic tlb2_RFQ_Details1). [tbl2_RFQ_Details1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0eqm.jpg). The Item's quotes are in the table and form "tbl4_Fabricator_Quotes" which has the textbox "Status". It also has check box (Buy) to manually select the "Fabricator"; so far everything works good, but what I want to do is to have the same field (Status) information in the "tbl2_RFQ_Details1" even if not "Buy" checkbox is selected.
The difficult part for me, is to show the Status in the tbl2_RFQ_Details1 when a Fabricator in tbl4_Fabricator_Quotes is no selected. When a Fabricator is no selected yet, the status is "Cotizando" (Waiting for Quotes) but the thing is, I have more than one Fabricator, so I can't bring the status "Cotizando" to the tbl2_RFQ_Details1. As I said before, bring the other status is no problem because I select the BUY checkbox and by using an expression the status shows up (See pic2).
[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHYBX.jpg). I have tried different expressions using DLookUp as well as IIF together and separate and/or changing the values, but I can't get the results that I want. Again I hope some you can help me. I will really appreciate it.

Some help with expression IIF and DLookUp in MS Access